# Update Gedit side panel

Tags: python, pygtk, gedit, pygobject

I'm writing my first gedit plugin, a directory browser for the sidebar.

Show sidepanel with content of the cwd.

> self._side_widget = self.get_dir() #returns a Gtk.Treestore obj
>
> self.side_panel = self.window.get_side_panel()
>
> self.side_panel.add_item(self._side_widget, "dir-browser", "Directory
>   Browser", None)
>
> self.side_panel.activate_item(self._side_widget)

With a double click on a file, i open the document in gedit.

With a double click on a directory I change the directory and I want to update the content of the side panel.

I can build the a new treestore from the current working directory with self.get_dir() but I don't know how to update self.side_panel.

Comment: You do know that Gedit already has a directory browser built in?

Comment: Yes I know. I'm writing this plugin for learning purpose only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either empty the current tree store and fill it again from the new directory, or call `set_model(new_treestore)` on the tree view widget. It will update itself.